# Encoding multidimensional arrays in raw transaction data

Tags: solidity, data-types, encoding

Say, there is a function in a contract:

```
function foo(uint[2][2][2] numbers) {}
```

How the following array should be encoded in raw transaction data?

```
[
    [
        [ 1, 2 ],
        [ 3, 4 ]
    ],
    [
        [ 5, 6 ],
        [ 7, 8 ]
    ]
]
```

What if array is incomplete?

```
[
    [
        [ 1, 2 ]
    ],
    [
        [ 5 ],
        [ 7, 8 ]
    ]
]
```

Also, is there a plan to support dynamically-sized multidimensional arrays (e.g. `uint[][][]`, `string[][]`) in function arguments / return values?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2708

Comment: Hi @Edward - it might be worth adding some details from that link as an answer, just in case the comment goes missing (or the contents of the link get moved). It'll also prevent your question from going stale and unanswered :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official answer from the Ethereum team:

> This should be working now (in latest nightly) via using the new
>   experimental encoder:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract C {
  function f() returns (uint[][][] memory) {
  }
}
```

> Note: this will turn on an experimental feature (which is also noted
>   in the metadata) and should not be used in production. It is only
>   about encoding, decoding is not supported.